# Is it ok to keep both xyz.in and xyz.com live with different but similar data?

Tags: seo, domains, multiple-domains, local-seo

Our startup creates store-locator and microsites for brands in an automated manner using template approach under a new domain. So for one of our client (brand), we made its store locator live for all its India stores (suppose *xyz.in*) a month ago and it's performing very well.

Now the brand wants us to do the same thing with its stores in 3 other countries. Currently, we are live on domain *xyz.in*, so we cannot make the new pages live under this domain.

**So will it be ok to make *xyz.com* live with the data of stores in other countries and keep the data of India stores under *xyz.in* ?**

**Or should I take *xyz.in* down and make all the data live under xyz.com (I am scared that then we will face the duplicate content issue, as most of the pages have already been crawled for *xyz.in*) ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do either - as long as there is no duplicate content on the two sites there is no reason for either to be punished by Google.

If you attempt the second option, I would use some URL naming convention that is recognisable by Google such as `xyz.com/en` , `xyz.com/in` etc.

And use Google Search Console at https://www.google.com/webmasters to notify Google that you want to transfer the existing links from `xyz.in` to `xyz.com/in`.  Ensure that you setup both old and new site URLs on Google Search Console, and select "Change of Address" under the Settings icon for the old site and point to the new site.

Then setup redirects for the pages on the old site, so that it redirects traffic from `xyz.in` to `xyz.com/in`. I would use htaccess and set permanent redirects which means you could specify exact new URLs for each request. You may also need to use htaccess at the new server to correctly route these requests. (There are plugins for different CMS platforms which can help you with this if you don't want to get your hands dirty with htaccess, however none of them will give you the power and flexibility of learning mod-rewrite rules in htaccess.)

Another option is to use a DNS redirect to redirect any request to the old site across to the new site, but depending on the options available at wherever your domain is managed will determine whether you can correctly route requests to the appropriate page. In that case you would want to add conditions in the htaccess on the new site to receive those redirects and make sure users land appropriately. To go into depth on how to do this would be beyond the scope of this answer, but there are plenty of pages on SE to help you with that.

Keep an eye on the Google links, test them with your setup and make sure that they are being renamed by Google and are landing where they should go.

In that way you should lose no link juice, and Google will know that you are not creating duplicate content. Obviously, you will want to take the old site down once the indexes are transferred.

Answer (score 1):

Keep both sites. Everyone does that. `.in` is localized so that's a great way to advertise to local audience and in future even split off infrastructure/resources.

Here's what I'd do.
In Google or any similar search webmaster console, you add both domains
Select the `primary domain` as `xyz.com`
mark `xyz.in` as Alias or even mark it as a Country target. Which is good for SEO since it directs India users to .in

To prevent duplicate url in search engine use this method called URL canonicalization. It allows you to tell a Search Engine which domain to use for a page and also give it both URL. Letting search engine know a page has a duplicate is being a good user, there is nothing wrong with having dupes as long as you are not doing something wrong and be forthwith about it.

Here the reference on Canonical URL
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en